# what properties should be set for my SMTP

Tags: php, html, apache, debian-jessie, mail-sender

I have setup a Website based on HTML with the exception of a contact.php page. I am hosting this website on my Rasberry Pi 3 computer on Debian flavor of linux Jesse Light. This is headless as it hosts my Portfolio website. I am using Apache2 webserver and installed sendmail as my Mail Transfer Agent (MTA). The problem is I have been spinning my wheels researching for the past week and I am stuck.

My issue is I send email from my php contact page on my live server but nothing ever arrives in my inbox after sending it. I get a mail sent message from my php script after about a minute after sending but then Nothing arrives in the inbox. I am thinking My SMTP on my php.ini is not correct. I put my website domain name FQ name. I am using Microsoft Exchange Online hosted email domain by GoDaddy. Also, anyone have any good advise on what my from / to should be set to on my SMTP configurations?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a direct reject to me.

Some hints:

- check the SMTP logs from your MS Exchange server (if a connection has been opened and potentially been refused for whatever reason)
- check the PHP / Apache logs and see, whether an PHP fatal error or warning occured (mybad bad credentials or wrong port?)
- I have had bad experiences with MS Exchange server and SMTP, make sure its proper setup.
- check the credentials and settings from an independent client to see if they work flawless.

Hope that helps. Otherwise please provide more details and log samples.

Comment: Having issues with my remote on MAC so, I'll be sure to investigate those logs as soon as I get home so I can then remote in. Thanks for the feedback Reacher234. :) I'll update later when I get home to check these logs out.

Answer (score -1):

Is your contact.php program hosted on the Godaddy server? If yes- It's not possible to send mail through Godaddy shared hosting servers using your own SMTP settings.  You can only send from Godaddy's relay server when using a shared hosting plan. If you wanted to be able to send through your own SMTP servers, you'd need to be hosting with either a VPS or Dedicated Server plan.

Check maillog on your server and you will get the smtp connection timeout errors.

Let me know, in case the problem is something different- will try to address it.

Comment: The server is identified as Office356.com but my Email domain name is via Godaddy. If I used the Microsoft Exchange that would be my mail server right? So Sendmail server is not needed? I can send email and receive email just fine on Outlook on desktop apps on windows, mac and  android. Just the sending part I am running into problems from my website's php form. I did look at the maillog var/mail/log I see mostly unable to identify domain name or something like that.